# One single nic, multiple IPs, multiple hostnames

Tags: networking

I know I can setup, via aliasing, multiple IPs for the same NIC. I was wondering if I can have each IP correspond to a different host name, so that I can ping them from a windows machine.

Say the NIC is bound to three IP 192.168.2.3-4-5
I want something:
192.168.2.3 server1
192.168.2.4 server2
192.168.2.5 server3

So that from a client (Windows?) machine I can ping all three of them successfully.

Thanks

Comment: I know I can do that via bridge/VM with multiple NICs, but I am trying to avoid having to create a VM just for it and have it work natively.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Being able to ping each ip address serves no useful purpose. What's your end goal?

Comment: The DNS / host names are simply text entries mapping to an IP address. So, as long as you have IP addresses set on the server and DNS / host entries set up, you can access them via those names.

Comment: I am trying to use SAMBA aliasing. SAMBA allows to expose a different configuration via Server Variables, one of them being the IP address of the server.